# How to subtract 3 to returned value

Tags: python, addition, subtraction

As long as value is under 13 :
add 4 to original value (0) and print value
take that value and subtract 3

```py
n = 0
while n < 13: 
    print (n)
    n = n + 4 

print('end of program')
```

need to get this solution:

`0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8,5,9,6,10,7,11,8,12,9,13`

Comment: Add 4, print it, subtract 3, print it.  Repeat while less than 13.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way is to keep track of whether you're on an even or odd iteration (i.e. whether you should add 4 or subtract 3) using a boolean. This code creates the desired output:

```
n = 0
even = True
print(n)

while n < 13:
    if even:
        n = n + 4
        print(n)
        even = False
    else:
        n = n - 3
        print(n)
        even = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that collects the values in a list. Append the first value, then add 4, check if the value is still less than 13 and then append that value, then subtract 3 and do it all over again.

```
In [2]: def func(n):
    ...:     lst = []
    ...:     while n < 13:
    ...:         lst.append(n)
    ...:         n += 4
    ...:         if n < 13:
    ...:             lst.append(n)
    ...:         n -= 3
    ...:     return lst
    ...:
    ...:

In [3]: func(0)
Out[3]: [0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 10, 7, 11, 8, 12, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
n = 0
print(n, end=",")
while True:
    n += 4
    print(n, end="")
    if n >= 13:
        break
    n -= 3
    print(",", n, sep="", end=",")
print()
```

Prints:

```
0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8,5,9,6,10,7,11,8,12,9,13
```

Answer (score 0):

one of many approach

```
n = 0
while n < 13:
    print(n, end=',')
    n += 4
    if n == 13:
            print(n, end='\n')
            break
    elif n > 13:
            break
    n -= 3
```

output

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13
```